# User info to txt File to be read

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I have an issue with my program. Im trying to be able to use all the info typed into text boxes and store them to a txt file. I have an address class to format the info and a form.

I have the address class here:

```
public class Addresses
{
    private string name { get; set; }
    private string address { get; set; }
    private string city { get; set; }
    private string state { get; set; }
    private string zipCode { get; set; }
    private string phoneNum { get; set; }

    public Addresses()
    {
    }

    public Addresses(string fName, string ad, string cty, string st, string  zip, string pNum)
    {
        name = fName;
        address = ad;
        city = cty;
        state = st;
        zipCode = zip;
        phoneNum = pNum;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Name: " + name +
            "\nAddress: " + address +
            "\nCity: " + city +
            " State: " + state +
            " Zip Code: " + zipCode +
            "\nPhone#: " + phoneNum;
            ;
    }

}

}
```

And form class here:

```
using System;
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace AddressBook
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private StreamReader inFile;
        private StreamWriter outFile;


        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }




        private void menuExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void fileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Created by ME!\nByron Buyck\nAKA\n毕容谦" +
                "\n2016");
        }

        private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                openBox.ShowDialog();
                inFile = new StreamReader(openBox.FileName);
                lblMessage.Text = "File Name: " + openBox.FileName;
                readFile();
                inFile.Close();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }

        private void readFile()
        {
            string data = inFile.ReadLine();

            while (data != null)
            {
                txtInfo.Text += data + "\r\n";
                data = inFile.ReadLine();


            }
        }

        private void btnClr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtInfo.Text = "";
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox3.Text = "";
            textBox5.Text = "";
            textBox6.Text = "";
            textBox7.Text = "";
            textBox8.Text = "";


        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Addresses User = new Addresses();
            textBox1.Text = User.name;
            textBox3.Text = User.address;
            textBox5.Text = User.city;
            textBox6.Text = User.state;
            textBox7.Text = User.zipCode;
            textBox8.Text = User.phoneNum;
            User.ToString();

            try
            {
                saveBox.ShowDialog();
                outFile = new StreamWriter(saveBox.FileName, true);
                outFile.WriteLine(txtInfo.Text);
                outFile.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;

            }
        }


        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {




        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox7_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txtInfo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
    }
```

Please someone tell me what I've done wrong. The file get's saved, but nothing shows up in the file that gets saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following reversed in btnSave_Click:

```
Addresses User = new Addresses();
textBox1.Text = User.name;
textBox3.Text = User.address;
textBox5.Text = User.city;
textBox6.Text = User.state;
textBox7.Text = User.zipCode;
textBox8.Text = User.phoneNum;
User.ToString();
```

In the above case you would be setting your text boxes to the User's values. When you call ToString, the values will just be undefined because they were never set in the default constructor.

Instead you probably want to do the opposite which is set the User's values based on the textboxes and then get the User's information.

Edit: Your Addresses class has private variables though so you wouldn't be able to directly set the User information via the Form class. However you could use the other constructor and then call ToString within the btnSave_Click function.

```
Addresses User = new Addresses(textBox1.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox5.Text, textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text, textbox8.Text);
txtInfo.Text = User.ToString();
```